# How add entity from table many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Create entity Desk:

```
var desk = new Desk()
           {
           x = Convert.ToInt32(Canvas.GetLeft(item)),
           y = Convert.ToInt32(Canvas.GetTop(item)),
           width = item.Width,
           height = item.Height,
           };
```

Add to table Desks:

```
m_RoomsContext.Desks.Add(desk);
```

And I need add desk.id and other id_room, but desk.id == 0.

```
m_RoomsContext.RoomToStandartDesks.Add(new RoomToStandartDesk()
                       {
                           id_room = int.Parse(btnSave.Tag.ToString()),
                           id_desk = desk.id
                       }
                       );
```

How update desk ? or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to update the changes to entities?  If so:

```
m_RoomsContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: desk - not have id. id - is primary key, and add auto.

Comment: Denis, as soon as you save changes into database this id will be updated (if, of course, there is autoincrement set up on this field in database).